# Normal operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T\colon V \to V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional
>   complex inner product space $V$.
>
> 1. Prove that if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are complex numbers such that $|\lambda| = |\mu| = 1$,
>      then $λT + \mu T^{\ast}$ is normal.
> 2. If $||T(v)||=||T^{\ast}(v)||$ for all vectors $v ∈ V$ , prove that $T$ is normal.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: So for 2 I have realized that ||T(v)||=||T*(v)|| shows that 
<T(v), T(v)> = <T*(v), T*(v)> but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Do you know what a normal operator is?

Comment: An operator is normal if it satisfies TT* = T*T.